# How can one keep track of database rows which an application read last time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am developing an application which will read a very large database table in Oracle. It will then process it and save the results. One way to do it would be to process all the rows in one go. It will take a long time to run and also when new rows are added to the table there is no way I can get those rows.

So I am looking for a solution where I can read only some rows at a time and on the next read of the table leave those rows and read other rows.

Any other solution which avoids reading the whole table in one go, is also welcome.

Comment: What is a "very large" table? In terms of rows/bytes. How long takes the processing of one row?

Comment: It had 8 billion rows. But it should not matter as my questions is whether there is some way of knowing that which rows are processed and which are not on every run?

Comment: @PrinceKumar How did you manage this? I have a similar requirement where I need to read from a primary database and store the record (after some transformation ) into secondary no-sql db. The application doing so need to keep track of the row processed last time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a "flag" column:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD (new_flag BOOL DEFAULT FALSE);
```

... then flag the rows as you process them:

```generic
// job is starting
do {
    db.startTransaction();
    workingSet = db.select(
        "SELECT primary_key, other_columns FROM your_table WHERE new_flag = FALSE LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE"
    );
    if (workingSet.size != 0) {
        db.query(
            "UPDATE your_table SET new_flag = TRUE WHERE primary_key IN " + workingSet
        );
        db.commit();
        doSomethingUseful(workingSet);
    } else {
        db.rollback();
    }
} while (workingSet.size != 0);

// job's done, let's cleanup
db.query("UPDATE your_table SET new_flag = FALSE WHERE new_flag = TRUE");
```

---

*OP initially tagged her question with [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), but it appears that the target RDBMS is Oracle. The SQL syntax is correct for MySQL, I don't know if it will work as-is with Oracle. Also,there may be better native Oracle solutions for this.*

Comment: It will not work for Oracle with this syntax. However the concept of adding a flag column certainly is a (one of) correct one regardless of RDBMS. Index on this column may help, but a lot depends on what a "very large database" actualy is

Answer (score 0):

With billions of records I guess/hope/recommend that the table is partitioned. Probably by some "create_date" column but that is not that important.

Billions of records also mean that you have to process one row (much) faster than 1ms to be able to compute the whole table in a "finite" time.

I assume that the records are once created and not updated outside your process.

There 2 options. Either you are (likely) able to process an entire partition in one go or not. If you can do it, than create a separate table which logs partitions and pick one unprocessed (not the one records are currently created in) and process it.

If the partitions are so big (or table is not partitioned) that you are unlikely to process an entire partition in one go then you have several options and it IMO may vary from situation to situation which approach is the best.

1) add a flag column

```
alter table T add processed number;
```

and select (bulk collect limit) some of the unprocessed, process them and bulk write the flag

2) use existing column for getting a deterministic subset (PK, create_date) and select those rows that are between some boundaries. Process the set and update info about the boundaries in a separate config table

Both approaches have the disadvantage that it will read some database blocks over and over again in subsequent starts of the processing. With the flag column it would be multiblock operations. With PK it would be singleblock operations but it would be cached.

3) A rather uncommon option with highest implementation complexity, but best performance would be to compute to a separate config table rowid boundaries and then process a subset set by these boundaries. E.g.

```
select/update T where rowid > lower_bound and rowid <= higher_bound;
```

Best case of a "common" solution still is IMO to process an entire partition in one go.